# Complex Rails Active Record query to select record with true result for that day else latest updated else created record for day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am having following important columns in a table,

- **customer_approval (boolean)**
- **created_at (datetime)**
- **updated_at (datetime)**

There is a possibility that multiple records might be present for the day. One these records for a day might have customer_approval marked as TRUE.

How can we write a query to get result set as follows:

1. select only one record per day even if multiple are present for that day
2. First preference for selection of record must be given to record where customer_approval is true
3. If records don't fit in the above criteria select the latest entry which was created or updated based on created_at or updated_at column for that day
4. Select all the records based on a date range (From date - To Date) when they were created.

Also adding an example:
Table Data

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| row_id | customer_approval | created_at | updated_at |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+
|      1 | TRUE              | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-01 |
|      2 | FALSE             | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-01 |
|      3 | NIL               | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-01 |
|      4 | NIL               | 2017-12-02 | 2017-12-02 |
|      5 | FALSE             | 2017-12-03 | 2017-12-03 |
|      6 | NIL               | 2017-12-03 | 2017-12-03 |
|      7 | NIL               | 2017-12-04 | 2017-12-05 |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

Expected ResultSet for Date Range 2017-12-01 & 2017-12-05 :

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| row_id | customer_approval | created_at | updated_at |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+
|      1 | TRUE              | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-01 |
|      4 | NIL               | 2017-12-02 | 2017-12-02 |
|      6 | NIL               | 2017-12-03 | 2017-12-03 |
|      7 | NIL               | 2017-12-04 | 2017-12-05 |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry about the poor table formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (created_at) row_id, customer_approval, created_at
FROM the_table
ORDER BY customer_approval DESC, created_at DESC;
```

In rails

```
TheTable.select("DISTINCT ON (created_at) row_id, customer_approval, created_at")
        .order(customer_approval: :desc, created_at: :desc )
```

Comment: Thanks @Salil But I am not able to understand why Order in descending fashion on customer_approval when it is a boolean. Cheers

Comment: If you not mention `ASC/DESC` it will take `ASC` by default. For boolean field with non null values `ASC order` is `false, true' & `DESC order`  is `true, false`. In your case you want only one row for each customer, if `customer_approval` is `true`, if it is not present we will fetch latest record with `customer_approval = false` by adding order `created_at DESC`

Comment: Is it working for you? if yes, you should upvote & accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It not giving the desired result. I am updating the question for more clarity. Bear with me. Cheers.

Comment: Not getting the desired result. All records are returned with multiple records for the single date. Can you please check? Thanks.

Comment: Your `created_at` format must be `datetime` which is creatin a problem

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not perfect, and you should think about exceptions.

**Model**

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord

  scope :approval, -> { where customer_approval: true }
  scope :waiting, -> { where customer_approval: nil }

  scope :for_day, ->(date) {
    where(
      arel_table[:created_at].eq(date)
      .or(arel_table[:updated_at].eq(date))
    )
  }

  def self.last_change
    order(created_at: :desc, updated_at: :desc).first
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def fetch_customers(first, last)
  result = []

  first.upto(last) do |date|
    customer = Customer.for_day(date).approval.first
    customer ? (result << customer) : (result << Customer.for_day(date).waiting.last_change)
  end

  result
end

# first = Date.parse('2017-12-01')
# last = Date.parse('2017-12-05')
# fetch_customer(first, last)
```

**P.s.** Hope your rails version 4+ (for Arel table)